# Access forbidden on xampp server - localhost

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am totally confused with my problem. It is not the new one but I can not find the right combination of words and tags for my config - files, because some of the solutions from the same questions here are not working.

I am trying to open the site, which is locally hosted by xampp server from my phone.
The address I am using is : ip:8080/blog.dev:8080 and I am getting 403 - error.

My conf - files:

1. httpd-vhosts.conf

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:8080>
      DocumentRoot "D:/PHP/xampp/htdocs/blog/public"
      ServerName blog.dev
      <Directory "D:/PHP/xampp/htdocs/blog/public">
         Order Deny,Allow
         Allow from all
         Require all granted
      </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
2. httpd.conf

   ```
   DocumentRoot "D:/PHP/XAMPP/htdocs"
   <Directory "D:/PHP/XAMPP/htdocs">
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ```

I tried to add "Options Indexes FollowSymLinks"but that's not help

Comment: What apache logs say ?

Comment: @AdrienLeber "[Sun Nov 06 22:24:57.410582 2016] [core:error] [pid 12204:tid 1876] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client 192.168.1.103:43929] AH00127: Cannot map GET /blog.dev:8080/ HTTP/1.1 to file"

Comment: You have a case issue : "XAMPP" & "xampp". Also what is the permission level on folder and sub-folders of `D:/php/xampp/htdocs/` ?

Comment: What looks like your C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file ?

Comment: @AdrienLeber it is 
"127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       blog.dev
127.0.0.1 acdid.acdsystems.com"

Answer (score 0):

Following your logs and the provided link, I'd say that the second port number is "too much".

Try access your website through `http://blog.dev:8080/`.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

If the ip is 192.168.1.102, you have to replace the

```
127.0.0.1    blog.dev
```

with that ip in your host file :

```
192.168.1.102    blog.dev
```

And then, access it through http://blog.dev/.

Comment: No. Still not. I am trying to this from phone so that's why I need ip.
This http://blog.dev:8080/ does not work. And this 192.168.1.102:8080/blog.dev/ - 404 error. And 192.168.1.102/blog.dev:8080/  - runtime rror